# Why I don't have typo in vuex/orm?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-orm

I create a `User` model using [vuex-orm](https://github.com/vuex-orm/vuex-orm) and I want to access to its property `email`.

but the ide/typescript doesn't fill the properties.

[image]

vuex-orm is supported with typescript typo.

When I try to access using JavaScript I able to execute this code and get the value.

```
const email = allUsers[0].email;
```

[My code in codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-architecture-dwbcq?file=/src/main.js)

Comment: Fields are not mapped to class properties. You need to do this yourself or use a property decorator. Since you're not using Typescript, it makes little to no difference.